# Make svg width 100%

Tags: svg

I have a SVG but I can't set its width to 100%. How can I fix it?

```css
body {
background: black
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="50" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 317 13.2">
 <g transform="translate(-0.5 -284)" style="
    width: 1500px;
">
  <path fill="#fff" width="100%" transform="matrix(.265 0 0 .265 0 284)" d="m0 0v50h1200v-50h-560a40 40 0 0 1-40 40 40 40 0 0 1-40-40h-560z" fill-rule="evenodd" style="paint-order:markers fill stroke"></path>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I tried to write attribute width="100%" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure it works. I'ts only the viewbox that does not span the width. What result are you looking for? Fixed height or fixed aspect ratio?

Comment: @ccprog I want 100% width of white background.

Comment: And what height?

Comment: @ccprog height 50px

Comment: Then add an attribute `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the `<svg>` element. Note the cutout will no longer be circular if dimensions are distorted.

Comment: Circle then is resize, I don't need circle to be resized.

Comment: How exactly do you want to display something that's 100% width, 50px in height without distortion? preserveAspectRatio has various options you can experiment with.